Questions about the DAA instruction in Intel 8080 processor
In the intel 8080 manual the DAA description says to follow these steps:

If the value of the least significant 4 bits of the
accumulator is greater than 9 or if the AC flag
is set, 6 is added to the accumulator.

If the value of the most significant 4 bits of the
accumulator is now greater than 9, or if the CY
flag is set, 6 is added to the most significant 4
bits of the accumulator.


I'm not sure if the second step relies on the changes that happened to the accumulator during the 1st step, here is my try:
void DAA(State8080 *state) {
    uint8_t acc_val = state->registers[A];
    uint8_t val = 0;
    if (((state->registers[A] & 0x0F) > 0x09) || state->cc.ac) {
        val += 0x06;
        state->registers[A] += 0x06;
    }

    if (((state->registers[A] >> 4) > 0x09) || state->cc.cy) {
        val += 0x60;
        state->registers[A] += 0x60;
        state->cc.cy = 1;
    }
    uint8_t res = state->registers[A];

    _update_flag_z(state, res);
    _update_flag_s(state, res);
    _update_flag_p(state, res);
    _update_flag_ac_add(state, acc_val, val, false);

}


"is now" refers to the state after the previous step. This is plain English.

Any carry-out has to be considered.

https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/2f3vxx/what_does_8080_instruction_daa_do/

What does _update_flag_ac_add do?

Also note the following from the manual: If a carry out of the least significant four bits occurs during Step (1), the Auxiliary Carry bit is set; otherwise it is
reset. Likewise, if a carry out of the most significant four bits occurs during Step (2), the normal Carry bit is set; otherwise, it is unaffected.

@IanAbbott it adds the lower 4 bits of the two arguments together and checks if it the result is bigger than 0xF and assigns the truth value of that to the ac flag, it also adds a carry if the carry argument is true.
